# DataGrid storing value from ID column after clicking ButtonColumn

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have dynamically created a DataGrid using data from a database. I have hard coded a ButtonColumn and when I click this button I want to have a function which loads more data from the database onto the page.

In order to do this I need to store the ID value which is on the same row as the button I just clicked.

I also need to make the ID column not visible to the user I just want to display the Description and ButtonColumn. Here is a screenshot of what Is being output at the moment.

[image: Output DataGrid]

I just want the first and third column to be displayed. Also If I was to click the first row I want to store the value 1 in a variable so I am then able to use that in a SQL query later on.

This is how I am dynamically adding the data:

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM Table1 WHERE[Part Number] like 'A%'");
 DataGridView1.DataBind();
```

I think this is probably wrong if I want to hide one of the columns because by doing it this way I am unable to access the individual columns.

This is what the front end for the DataGrid looks like:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="DataGridView1" ShowHeader="False" CssClass="" GridLines="None" OnItemCommand="LoadNewData">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" Text="Display Data" CommandName="DisplayData"/>  
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: so when user clicks on LinkButton your query will be what? i dont get it.

Comment: @Badiparmagi If I clicked the link on the first row all I want to do is pull the Id value for that same row into a variable thats it

Comment: i could help but never used DataGrid control. why not DataGridView? just asking

Comment: @Badiparmagi I have just changed it all the GridView now since I am using asp.net

Comment: check my answer